# Relative velocity motion in this case

Tags: kinematics, velocity, relative-motion

Take a look at this picture, the point $a$ is the location of the wheel's center in the robot's frame {$0$}. The point $c$ is attached to a robot's mass center. The angular velocity $\omega$ is the robot's angular velocity about $c$. The $v_a$ term represents the tangential velocity of the wheel (i.e. $v_a=r\dot{\phi}$). The relative velocity between $v_c$ and $v_a$ is

$$
v_c = v_a + \omega \times {}^0r_{c/a}
$$

where ${}^0r_{c/a}$ is the distance between $a$ and $c$ represented in frame {0}.

[image]

Now what happens if the orientation of frame {1} differs from frame {0}? How can I use the above formula? See the below picture.

[image]

My solution is to represent $v_a$ in frame {0} by multiplying it by the rotation matrix ${}^0_1R$ and use

$$
v_c = {}^0_1R v_a + \omega \times {}^0r_{c/a}
$$

Is this correct?